# load XML certificate chain

Tags: c#, x509certificate

for initializing a COPP session in need to obtain driver certificate chain. now i have a certificate chain in XML format like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<c:CertificateCollection xmlns:c="http://schemas.microsoft.com/DRM/2004/02/cert" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" c:Version="2.0">
<c:Certificate>
  <c:Data>
     <c:PublicKey>
        <KeyValue>
           <RSAKeyValue>
              <Modulus>1UwBXelx+u0K4uPpIyNa0h3Xwgm+KQve4xh9dZ7SaU6cv1WPcE09mI34o9Jwbo1VT+HPCBw7ITSYLqDOMYIEGUEQjVmuZB4Ug59mRTLJOz3njHdoYh4bUZydTFY8tZ57U4KKS0izihhqGbuA7hvSVQszrf+utI+ctnZAWxoF6QMuRU3NuLeXXXm10fbsmu33IEudgCEehR4etg7tUYnW6hzT9Yoe7uVVYinMTyumYeDx0gxDLvklqdIAmDUOzLSeR/nsRcMAxYeKlCPVmhfEAiUngmqQQEC3Pt/K+D/y0acdxwuDfpWYt7CPrelU/DCcHwCTMZDL5udsqJMTdd7kQQ==</Modulus>
              <Exponent>AQAB</Exponent>
           </RSAKeyValue>
        </KeyValue>
     </c:PublicKey>
     <c:KeyUsage>
        <c:EncryptKey>1</c:EncryptKey>
     </c:KeyUsage>
     <c:SecurityLevel>2000</c:SecurityLevel>
     <c:ManufacturerData>
        <c:ManufacturerName>NVidia Corporation</c:ManufacturerName>
        <c:ManufacturerURL>http://www.nvidia.com</c:ManufacturerURL>
        <c:ModelName>Graphics Driver</c:ModelName>
        <c:ModelNumber>Version 320.49</c:ModelNumber>
     </c:ManufacturerData>
     <c:Features>
        <c:WMDRMReceiver>1</c:WMDRMReceiver>
        <c:COPPCertificate>1</c:COPPCertificate>
     </c:Features>
  </c:Data>
  <Signature>
     <SignedInfo>
        <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315" />
        <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/DRM/2004/02/CERT/Rsa-sha1" />
        <Reference>
           <Transforms>
              <Transform Algorithm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/DRM/2004/02/CERT/Data" />
              <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315" />
           </Transforms>
           <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" />
           <DigestValue>ZaHL3l6sO717q3rTyv2WUENZIpE=</DigestValue>
        </Reference>
     </SignedInfo>
      <SignatureValue>dm+EEcA9d1whKF4YIha1CSIVtk3P/E1pOsIVthqzJUivwAeJOIi+k7PB+6MtsjkmsGVRaiIZni36z5gEFaqxX9uXUf1NxA+Dwt0bcIgLnBz6ELoZRkVTuvgEnfxmwqcn2Cg6MM5IPVHPql2Tk0UMbxMMWeDC6mClnEzUNvTkaH8zYPXCX+G6aE6Wh9UUhn/qmwHcFHZLAFXQTzB850T/JaZJgTg4P8+vMEL1VxeNqNDEDzH5YdEYOMS9ruD8lJxDm8j1w2m4VNMUHW3XMwI7Glrr1D1PNRK5pqzkNKcWmuyIcSDW1JW8L/zHWsCHRJ51jJfxsfneEz8IOaLT2E0sKA==</SignatureValue>
     <KeyInfo>
        <KeyValue>
           <RSAKeyValue>
              <Modulus>tyKQLcKT6HzgDDBCqBFyFSbE/VAMCP/9FeaUWbIG/TKPal6woNrSqMmd9ged3SBXaLeX91qdUG10J+DtHevwzxm9iwwb4eMrVBE6W0QXB3xd4XiwvxICsI31X8HOGaSI+0wIgdGLSCySRYyXO+54a/2vpgd7AKxeIp6gW7QlySdstFrOwItc98/PfEX4c6yK0lAgqNoIlw5PKa6qe0I5PlW+wZAoSxDEMMo9GRQtTlvU8gX1k3tT4VyBpp2BzZsbA44AjWiEf0ZHm/b9LcrbvdrPNrVyo5P5djXTuL1zUclducxRa4H9H+aq0TmmHi78Rkaor2eEOZ4Ol47OeNfJEQ==</Modulus>
              <Exponent>AQAB</Exponent>
           </RSAKeyValue>
        </KeyValue>
     </KeyInfo>
  </Signature>
</c:Certificate>
<c:Certificate>
  <c:Data>
     <c:PublicKey>
        <KeyValue>
           <RSAKeyValue>
              <Modulus>tyKQLcKT6HzgDDBCqBFyFSbE/VAMCP/9FeaUWbIG/TKPal6woNrSqMmd9ged3SBXaLeX91qdUG10J+DtHevwzxm9iwwb4eMrVBE6W0QXB3xd4XiwvxICsI31X8HOGaSI+0wIgdGLSCySRYyXO+54a/2vpgd7AKxeIp6gW7QlySdstFrOwItc98/PfEX4c6yK0lAgqNoIlw5PKa6qe0I5PlW+wZAoSxDEMMo9GRQtTlvU8gX1k3tT4VyBpp2BzZsbA44AjWiEf0ZHm/b9LcrbvdrPNrVyo5P5djXTuL1zUclducxRa4H9H+aq0TmmHi78Rkaor2eEOZ4Ol47OeNfJEQ==</Modulus>
              <Exponent>AQAB</Exponent>
           </RSAKeyValue>
        </KeyValue>
     </c:PublicKey>
     <c:KeyUsage>
        <c:SignCertificate>1</c:SignCertificate>
     </c:KeyUsage>
     <c:SecurityLevel>2000</c:SecurityLevel>
     <c:ManufacturerData>
        <c:ManufacturerName>NVidia Corporation</c:ManufacturerName>
        <c:ManufacturerURL>http://www.nvidia.com</c:ManufacturerURL>
     </c:ManufacturerData>
  </c:Data>
  <Signature>
     <SignedInfo>
        <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315" />
        <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/DRM/2004/02/CERT/Rsa-sha1" />
        <Reference>
           <Transforms>
              <Transform Algorithm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/DRM/2004/02/CERT/Data" />
              <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315" />
           </Transforms>
           <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" />
           <DigestValue>MY4Anb+BiEs3rsY2Rr1hkIEcSXE=</DigestValue>
        </Reference>
     </SignedInfo>
     <SignatureValue>hbM9dDIB6EMxUsvMITDCyDJxoV6J/fD54XmiI8WLO8G7T1hApjzWxqlkxa+Ul0JXwHt70EFKWQe+niXBHR5wzb7Rcr5RCKkxSRepDBDU/1zJD+R6EtzMo0JdPvvrfInuKjOvuXhu7hBQCpOPqSJUNZVT0zWrSIl44+xqI4wRGM0=</SignatureValue>
     <KeyInfo>
        <KeyValue>
           <RSAKeyValue>
              <Modulus>sAMzO56CMzRDa9cif2VfezUAA6e5XkSoyzHabqkIcIYIYEP2h61ukH93js6NDIG0bcGye/TlnxOtdeuKGmO0AOYbgJ7piCe0ZVyNdMn/1DrEflvHoA8YnMfl96/PoLrEwKw7j9FZR1XvjDpUl4mClydY5jrWy8xkNkuRCYh3PJE=</Modulus>
              <Exponent>AQAB</Exponent>
           </RSAKeyValue>
        </KeyValue>
     </KeyInfo>
  </Signature>
</c:Certificate>
<c:Certificate>
  <c:Data>
     <c:PublicKey>
        <KeyValue>
           <RSAKeyValue>
              <Modulus>sAMzO56CMzRDa9cif2VfezUAA6e5XkSoyzHabqkIcIYIYEP2h61ukH93js6NDIG0bcGye/TlnxOtdeuKGmO0AOYbgJ7piCe0ZVyNdMn/1DrEflvHoA8YnMfl96/PoLrEwKw7j9FZR1XvjDpUl4mClydY5jrWy8xkNkuRCYh3PJE=</Modulus>
              <Exponent>AQAB</Exponent>
           </RSAKeyValue>
        </KeyValue>
     </c:PublicKey>
     <c:KeyUsage>
        <c:SignCertificate>1</c:SignCertificate>
     </c:KeyUsage>
     <c:SecurityLevel>3000</c:SecurityLevel>
     <c:ManufacturerData>
        <c:ManufacturerName>Microsoft Corporation</c:ManufacturerName>
        <c:ManufacturerURL>http://www.microsoft.com</c:ManufacturerURL>
     </c:ManufacturerData>
  </c:Data>
  <Signature>
     <SignedInfo>
        <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315" />
        <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/DRM/2004/02/CERT/Rsa-sha1" />
        <Reference>
           <Transforms>
              <Transform Algorithm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/DRM/2004/02/CERT/Data" />
              <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315" />
           </Transforms>
           <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" />
           <DigestValue>6Oa4ngWiBGCi2UmRjCzkNaiiNUY=</DigestValue>
        </Reference>
     </SignedInfo>
     <SignatureValue>L8ae7IcXOLihq5n0q7T4KYcCuhRlhKU6qa5yy+4bmFS9qr7th2KIvSo6/zKrYTwnvMHuHyZK7Es3lIYCoBuVhr7sPABh7M//5WajfaKyMQpeTC28P3Htsv448o5YYTSXuIdzssY/EbBQ0PpOyf4zxvXZxIbRm8EpCpDm0DZZeIM=</SignatureValue>
     <KeyInfo>
        <KeyValue>
           <RSAKeyValue>
              <Modulus>pjoeWLSTLDonQG8She6QhkYbYott9fPZ8tHdB128ZETcghn5KHoyin7HkJEcPJ0Eg4UdSva0KDIYDjA3EXd69R3CN2Wp/QyOo0ZPYWYp3NXpJ700tKPgIplzo5wVd/69g7j+j8M66W7VNmDwaNs9mDc1p2+VVMsDhOsV/Au6E+E=</Modulus>
              <Exponent>AQAB</Exponent>
           </RSAKeyValue>
        </KeyValue>
     </KeyInfo>
  </Signature>
</c:Certificate>
</c:CertificateCollection>
```

now the question is, how i load this in c#? with object is for that? X509Certificate or something like this?

Answer (score 0):

To initialize the COPP session all you need is the device certificate's(the first one in the chain) public key. You can construct the public with the modulus and exponent provided in the XML.